# Is any smooth bounded function a contraction map?

Tags: real-analysis

$f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is smooth. It is known that $f$ is bounded both above and below. Does this imply that $f$ is a contraction map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $f(x)=2\arctan x$ is smooth and bounded but $|f(x)-f(0)| \leq |x-0|$ is not true.

In fact $\frac {f(x)} x \to 2$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: If there is an extra condition that $f$ is monotonously increasing?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju In this example $f'(x)=\frac 2 {1+x^{2}} >0$ so $f$ is strictly increasing.